# Generate Adjacency matrix from a Map

Tags: scala, functional-programming, hamiltonian-cycle

I know this is a lengthy question :) I'm trying to implement Hamiltonian Cycle on a dataset in Scala 2.11, as part of this I'm trying to generate Adjacency matrix from a Map of values.

Explanation:

Keys 0 to 4 are the different cities, so in below "allRoads" Variable

```
0 -> Set(1, 2) Means city0 is connected to city1 and city2
1 -> Set(0, 2, 3, 4) Means City1 is connected to city0,city2,city3,city4
.
.
```

I need to generate adj Matrix, for E.g:
I need to generate 1 if the city is connected, or else I've to generate 0, meaning

```
for: "0 -> Set(1, 2)", I need to generate: Map(0 -> Array(0,1,1,0,0))
```

input-

```
var allRoads = Map(0 -> Set(1, 2), 1 -> Set(0, 2, 3, 4), 2 -> Set(0, 1, 3, 4), 3 -> Set(2, 4, 1), 4 -> Set(2, 3, 1))
```

My Code:

```
val n: Int = 5
val listOfCities = (0 to n-1).toList
var allRoads = Map(0 -> Set(1, 2), 1 -> Set(0, 2, 3, 4), 2 -> Set(0, 1, 3, 4), 3 -> Set(2, 4, 1), 4 -> Set(2, 3, 1))
var adjmat:Array[Int] = Map()

  for( i <- 0 until allRoads.size;j <- listOfCities) {
    allRoads.get(i) match {
      case Some(elem) => if (elem.contains(j)) adjmat = adjmat:+1 else adjmat = adjmat :+0
      case _ => None
    }
  }
```

which outputs:

```
output: Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

Expected output - Something like this, please suggest if there's something better to generate input to Hamiltonian Cycle

```
Map(0 -> Array(0, 1, 1, 0, 0),1 -> Array(1, 0, 1, 1, 1),2 -> Array(1, 1, 0, 1, 1),3 -> Array(0, 1, 1, 0, 1),4 -> Array(0, 1, 1, 1, 0))
```

Not sure how to store the above output as a Map or a Plain 2D Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
val cities = listOfCities.toSet
allRoads.map { case (city, roads) =>
  city -> listOfCities.map(city => if ((cities diff roads).contains(city)) 0 else 1)
}
```

which outputs

```
Map(0 -> List(0, 1, 1, 0, 0), 1 -> List(1, 0, 1, 1, 1), 2 -> List(1, 1, 0, 1, 1), 3 -> List(0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 4 -> List(0, 1, 1, 1, 0))
```